# Php and HTML and die() for testing. Page does not die()

Tags: php, html, localhost

The localhost webpage should not display the HTML because in killed the page using die().

I can continue w/o sorting this but I am  really curious.
Lots of very good info came up as I searched this forum.

According to the tutorial that I am following,
The page should die() and not display the words Welcome
But it does display welcome at localhost/my website/

```
Index.php

<?php 
require 'conf.inc.php';

foreach($ip_blocked as $ip){
    if ($ip==$ip_address){
      die();
}
}
?>

<h1> welcome</h1>


conf.inc.php

<?php 

$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip_blocked = array('127,0,0,1', '100,100,100,100');
?>
```

Comment: That is because your if condition is false, the `$ip` is not equal to `$ip_address`. Check that.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$ip_blocked = array('127,0,0,1', '100,100,100,100');
```

to

```
$ip_blocked = array('127.0.0.1', '100.100.100.100');
```

. instead of ,

Answer (score 1):

```
$ip_blocked = array('127,0,0,1', '100,100,100,100');
```

should be

```
$ip_blocked = array('127.0.0.1', '100.100.100.100');
```

**Notice the DOTs!**

Plus you should not compare strings with IPs. Think IPs in terms of ranges, check against [private IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) if you're on a network with a `192.168.*.*` IP address.

`ip2long()` should be taken into consideration. Numbers compare faster than strings plus friendlier with range comparison *(in between)*.

Comment: Thanks. You guys are fast!! I just went to edit this code.  Using a tablet and reading from a Mac.  Still getting the 'welcome'

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion `vardump()` the `$ip_address` and the `$ip_blocked` and tell me what you see.

Comment: $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ip_blocked = array('100.100.100.100');
    
    var_dump($ip_blocked);
    var_dump($ip_address);

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion The output man. Not the code. What you see I the browser.

Comment: output:   array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "100.100.100.100" } string(3) "::1"      How can I jump to the next line ? When I hit return it posts this message.  please stick with me.  This is a great forum but the posts come in and in and we sort of get lost in the pile - I have noticed many question w/o answers.  see that ::1.... i had that question a while back.  when I use this code....foreach($ip_blocked as $ip) {
    echo $ip.'<br>';  i get this output: 127.0.0.1
100.100.100.100   not ::1.   I am confused. thanks for the help.

Comment: i am testing - learning.  i edited this to include the localhost ip 127.0.0.1  before var_dump()  $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ip_blocked = array('127.0.0.1','100.100.100.100');

Comment: ::1 is IPv6 loopback address, the localhost. Is your server on IPv6? You're on uncharted territory. I don't run the server on IPv6.

Comment: Darn. I have heard this before.  I am lost. Do I navigate in apache to look at my environmental variables to find out ?

Comment: I do not understand what that means or how this will have an effect on my testing.  Please explain this if you can.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion I don't really use Apache. I use IIS. Check the IP the site is bound to and make sure it's 127.0.0.1 and not ::1. Look here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html and check in your .conf files.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion I'm not gonna tell you here what IPv4 and IPv6 is. Google it!

Comment: Thanks.  I took me a while to check out .conf files - all familiar to me but not what I needed - I think.  I found this in my /etc directory.

Comment: ##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
It says DO NOT CHANGE THIS ENTRY.why do I need to change the second listing ?  thanks again.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion Can't help you! You use Linux and Apache. I know a bit of Apache, none of Linux. Post a new question on how to switch Apache to IPv4 and you might get better assistance.

Comment: Thanks anyway.  Forums really help the world.  Sharing info !!